# Unable to Extract text names in span tag using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table like below :

[image]

I'm trying to extract the Title names (highlighted) using below Selenium web driver code, but I'm getting output as `None` here:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')


wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get('https://www.deakin.edu.au/information-technology/staff-listing')
title = wd.find_elements_by_class_name('module__accordion--title')

for j in range(0,6): #Iterating through Titles i.e Profesor, Emeritus Professor....
  for i in title[j].find_elements_by_tag_name('span'): #Retrieving the title names
    i = i.get_attribute('text')
    print(i)
```

which results in below output :

[image]

So question is why I'm getting None instead of text ?

The code is present in the below Google Colab Link also.
Google Colab Link : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1R9-hzor-lDXddOsNzr3qFc_0qodrbU6g?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `i.text` or `i.get_attribute('innerText')`